# Spring JPA + EclipseLink ID generated in trigger

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have an ID column specified on an entity something like this:

```
@Id
@Column(name="id_seq", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=38)
private Long idSeq;
```

Pretty basic really.  The problem is that the field is set in a trigger, along with several other fields.

There doesn't seem to be a @Generated option that fits this need.  In good ol' JDBC I would do this with a getGeneratedKeys() call.

Is there a way to specify that this field needs to be updated in the entity after insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out that this gets the job done:

```
@ReturnInsert(returnOnly=true)
```

It is also imperative that you use MyJpaRespoitory.saveAndFlush() on the Entity vs. a .save() in order to see the values updated in the entity when the save is complete.

This worked on Oracle, but it may not work on all platforms.